# Unit Testing Scheduler in the FUTURE C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.0, quartz.net, moles

I'm using quartz.NET inside a scheduler project (class library) on my application, this is because i want the other projects to be agnostic of the actual implementation. In the future, if i want to change quartz for Castle Scheduler or Windows Scheduler or wathever... i will have the flexibility to change it.

I need to unit test weekly triggers on my Quartz.NET project, I started researching and found out what at the moment seemed to be a cool solution [MOLES](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3b41648-1c21-471f-a2b0-f76d8fb932ee/) this extension basically allows me to change the DateTime.Now and go TO THE FUTURE!!

In this case, one week from now, when the trigger is scheduled to fire, but after waiting a little time found with sadness that my triggers were not being activated, even when changing the time and Thread.Sleeping a couple of minutes...

The reason that I want to go to the future is because within the application I'm using different methods/triggers for each kind of request E.G.  Weekly, Weekly with recurrence, Monthly, Yearly

Has anyone else Unit Tested this kind of scenario?

Is there something that i'm passing by?

Is it possible with MOLES?

Comment: Triggers have methods like GetFireTimeAfter(DateTime) which will tell you next expected fire time. Wouldn't testing that be sufficient?

Comment: The thing is that i'm wrappint quartz.net into a façade in my own project so it's transparent for the other projects, and i want to test that from the outside, not directly on quartz.net triggers as outsider applications don't even know the existence of quartz triggers

Comment: i can't believe that no one else has ever found themselves in this situation...

Answer (score 5):

How about implementing something like

```
public interface IClock
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}

public class FakeClock : IClock
{
    DateTime Now { get; set; }
}

public class SystemClock : IClock
{
    DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
}
```

As you develop a facade, you could make your code depend on IClock, by replacing every call to DateTime.Now to IClock.Now.

The IClock dependency could be passed as a constructor parameter or directly to each method that requires it.

Then, your production code would use a SystemClock instance and your tests could rely on the FakeClock type to manipulatime the time and verify that some operation *do* occur at expected instant.

That kind of design (Inversion of Control) greatly benefits from working with a Dependency Injection container such as Castle Windsor, StructureMap, AutoFac, ...

**Note:** For further reference, similar implementation proposal in discussed in this [post](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/11/09/systemtime-versus-isystemclock-dependencies-revisited.aspx).

Comment: Quartz.NET's current development actually has this already. Just not released yet.

Comment: do you know when that is going to be released?  i was thinking over the weekend to get into the code of QUARTZ.net and implement it myself... but i would get stick to this particular version of quartz, and i don't like that much...

Answer (score 2):

I havn't tested this yet but when you tried Moles did you change DateTimeOffset or DateTime? Quartz.Net uses DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:

https://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/quartznet/src/Quartz/SystemTime.cs?hb=true

I think you should be able to do this without using moles though I havn't tested this either, just write

`SystemTime.UtcNow = () => new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)).UtcNow`

when you want to be five days into the future :)

Please note that the SystemTime-functionality require that you build Quartz from source, you can get the source at github:

https://github.com/lahma/quartznet